# MVC how to pre-populate IEnumerable<string> before attempting to populate with LINQ results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have quite a tricky question,
Basically I have a class that can have 3 string options, here is the basic class

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> Options {get;set;}
}
```

Now basically when this is called, I want to populate Options with 3 string objects, so in my razor view I can then use foreach and draw out 3 string input boxes.

But as the options are not required, when the user comes back to this page I will be using a LINQ query to pull out the options they selected.

So lets say they put two options, so after my LINQ query has been ran and it will return an IEnumerable of size 2, if I just leave it like that the view will only show 2 input boxes when I want to show 3, but with an IEnumerable I can not insert or add.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Create a new enumerable: `Options = Options.Concat(YourEnumerable);`

Comment: Your LINQ query will always return a new IEnumerable, not modify the existing one. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps instantiate you Options enumerable to a list, and then populate with you options, this can be done in the constructor

```
public void Person()
{
   var optionsList = new List<string>();\
//Add your options

   Options = optionsList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `Clone` that List and then you have to performe the rather opration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `List<string>` for the users selected options:

```
public void Repopulate()
{
     var allOptions = Options;
     // Linq Query..
     Options = allOptions;
}
```

Then have the view always show `Options`.